# Missing bracket

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to populate an Access table with some data. The problem is that I've got a missing bracket somewhere, and I really don't know where the missing bracket should be.

```
 OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
        MyConn.Open();
       using (OleDbCommand cmd = MyConn.CreateCommand())
  {
       // create command with placeholders
       cmd.CommandText =
          "INSERT INTO MasterTable "+
          "([Code], [Date],  [Percent]) "+
          "VALUES(@code, @date, @percent)";

       // Add named parameters
       cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
       {
           new OleDbParameter("@code", code),
           new OleDbParameter("@date", date),
           new OleDbParameter ("@percent", newVar)
       };

       // Execute
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact error message?

Answer (score 2):

```
   // add named parameters
   cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
   {
       new OleDbParameter("@code", code),
       new OleDbParameter("@date", date),
       new OleDbParameter ("@percent", newVar)
   }; // <-- missing parenthesis.
```

Comment: but I have to ask: is SO _really_ the best place to be asking about a formatting problem?